# Python error: IndentationError: expected an indented block

Tags: python

I've created a Python script to connect to an telnet server and i got this error:

```
IndentationError: expected an indented block
File "./exploit_war.py", line 16
connect.connect((hostname, 21))
```

A part of the script is follwoing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import socket


 hostname = sys.argv[1]
 username = "whatever"


connect = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:

connect.connect((hostname, 21))


except:


print "[-] connection error"
response = connect.recv(2000)
print response
sys.exit(1)
```

Can somebody help me?

That would be very nice..

Thanks

EDIT: Why does this part of code doesn't simulate an enter Key?:

```
connect.send("user %s\r\n" %username)
response = connect.recv(2000)
print response



connect.send("pass %s\r\n" %password)
response = connect.recv(2000)
print response
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indentation is everything in Python: it defines what is part of a loop, a function, an if statement, ... You should probably go through some basic tutorial (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/). For your code, this should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import socket

hostname = sys.argv[1] ## see how i changed the indentation of these two lines
username = "whatever"

connect = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    connect.connect((hostname, 21)) ## I  also changed the indentation here
except:
    print "[-] connection error" ## ... and here

response = connect.recv(2000) # this line will raise an error if the connection attempt fails
print response
sys.exit(1)
```

In your code, the lines `hostname = ...` and `username = ...` started with a space, they were indented. Python expects the following line to have the same indentation.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I'm new to linux and i didn't knew that.

Comment: You are welcome :-) however, this has nothing to do with linux

Comment: Yeah, i know. But Python is one of the most used programming languages of linux.

Comment: However, why does this code connect.send("user %s\%r\%n" %username)
response = connect.recv(2000)
print response



connect.send("pass %\%r\%n" %password)
response = connect.recv(2000)
print response

Comment: Not simulate an enter key?

Comment: Sorry, i just edited the question. So it's bettter to read

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with that. Also, that's a very different question ... so instead of editing your question, it is best to close this one and start a new question